# Assigning a new value to Hashtable without using the Add method

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

To add a new value to a dotnet Hashtable I've always used:

```
myHashtable.Add(myNewKey, myNewValue);
```

but I've just come across some code which does the following instead:

```
myHashTable[myNewKey] = myNewValue;
```

Is there any difference between the two methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To correct Sergej's answer a little...

- `Add` will indeed throw an exception if the key already exists.
- Using the indexer as a setter *won't* throw an exception (unless you specify a null key).
- Using the indexer as a getter will throw an exception if the key doesn't exist and if you're using a generic `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`. In the non-generic `IDictionary` implementations (e.g. `Hashtable`) you'll get a null reference. You can't use a null key for either one though - you'll get an `ArgumentNullException`.

Answer (score 3):

first will throw exception if there already were an item with given key and the second will throw an exception if there was no item with such key

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in handling duplicate values.

**myHashtable.Add()** throws ArgumentException if HashTable already contains element with your key.
**myHashTable[myNewKey]** replaces old value with new one.